# How to add web API to an existing MVC Hottowel project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes, breeze, hottowel

I have one Hottowel project created using it's template from Visual Studio. I want to add the Web API feature in that project. I have created a Web Api controller to the controller folder and tries to access like `"http://localhost:53397/api/Values"`  But I get an error saying `The resource cannot be found` error.

My controller code looks like below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MvcApplication8.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I have the cs file in APP_start folder called BreezeWebApiConfig.cs which contains the logic to map the route like below.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "BreezeApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
      );
```

Let me know If I am missing any configuration setting for Web APi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to decorate your ApiController like bellow :

```
[BreezeController]
public class NorthwindIBModelController : System.Web.Http.ApiController {

    readonly EFContextProvider<NorthwindIBContext> ContextProvider =
         new EFContextProvider<NorthwindIBContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public String Metadata() {
      return ContextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle) {
      return ContextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Customer> Customers() {
      return ContextProvider.Context.Customers;
    }
```

For more information have a look to breeze documentation [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/efcontextprovider).

Answer (score 0):

Its seems like you are making a wrong Url Request. Look at your breeze route configuration for WebApi. You need to Pass like that `http://localhost:53397/api/Values/Get` as breeze is using Controller action based routing.

Hope this will help.